# Use ShowDialog(form) where form is created on another thread?

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog, multithreading

I have a form that is used like a dialog, to be sure that the dialog get the correct parent the following method is used :

```
this.ShowDialog(myForm);
```

The problem is that this(my dialog form) and myForm is created on diffrent threads and when calling ShowDialog a crossthread exception will be thrown.

```
this.InvokeRequired = false
myForm.InvokeRequired = true
```

How do I handle this? Do I have to make sure that both are created on the same UI thread?

Comment: What thread are you creating the form on? What is `this`?

Comment: this is the winform that is used as a dialog. Its not known which thread the form and the dialog is created on it could be diffrent everytime in the current setup. Its all depends on the controller that creates the dialog and myform.

Comment: " Its not known which thread the form and the dialog is created on it could be diffrent everytime in the current setup." Therein lies your problem.

Comment: this.ShowDialog();??? Are you launching the form from within itself?

Comment: It is my understanding that in Winforms theres is one GUI thread. The form can be displayed only on the GUI thread so it will be a cross thread call when you show the form, because it will be showing on the GUI thread.

Comment: @David Heffernan > So I need to create both the dialog form and myform on the same thread, the UI thread. How do I find the UI thread?

Comment: @Bobby Alexander > Thats correct.

Comment: @Jodrell > There could be multiple UI threads as far as I know. How do I find the right one?

Comment: It's the thread that the main form was created from (I hope!)

Comment: @SnowJim, No I believe there is one UI thread, you will need to invoke whether or not you pass a parent form.

Comment: @Jodrell > You could create a new message pump with Application.Run(new form), do you mean that this messageppump will use the same UI thread as the main application(that also used Application.Run(new ThisMainForm()) ? How do I get the UI thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to ensure that all forms are created on the UI thread.

So rather than create the form on your background thread, pass a message to the UI thread to tell it to create and display the form.

Comment: Im use the WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current to put work in UI thread.

Comment: no ! common misconception. you can create any form in their own thread as long as they run in their own STAThread. C.f Application.Run

Answer (score 1):

Sample code with self-explanatory variables:

```
var logicToInvokeInsideUIThread = new MethodInvoker(() =>
{
    // ...

    ShowDialog(this);

    // ...
};

if (InvokeRequired)
{
    Invoke(logicToInvokeInsideUIThread);
}
else
{
    logicToInvokeInsideUIThread.Invoke();
}
```

I guess this is the better code logic to handle such cases. Sometimes `Invoke()` isn't needed.

Comment: Yes but this the InvokeRequired be checked on the dialog form(this) or on the myForm?

Comment: Check it on `myForm`. At the same place where you're trying to use `ShowDialog()`.

Comment: > I have now tried this and it gives me the same crossthread exception?

Answer (score 1):

Chris has suggested the right approach but as long as you are where you are now, you can try this:

```
public void ShowMe()
{
 if (_myForm.InvokeRequired)
                _myForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(ShowMe));
            else
                this.ShowDialog(_myForm); 
}
```

If the above doesnt work then pass the SynchronizationContext from your parent form to the class that is performing ShowDialog and perform Invoke on that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx

On a related note, you might want to have a relook at your design. Seems pretty convoluted.

Comment: > Have tested this and it throws the same crossthread exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me - this code is in the "Parent" Form which is running on the main thread and the child form is running from another thread, the Parent form is passed in as a parameter to the other thread as it has previously been opened on the main thread:

In the Parent Form on the main thread:

```
public delegate void ShowChildConsumer(Form ChildForm);
public void ShowChild(Form ChildForm)
{
     if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            var d = new ShowChildConsumer(ShowChild);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { ChildForm });
        }
        else
            ChildForm.ShowDialog(this);
    }
```

In the other thread:

```
frmChildForm childform = new frmChildForm();
parentform.ShowChild(childform);
result = childform.DialogResult;
childform.Dispose();
```

What is interesting is that even though the ShowDialog is called on the main thread - I can create and access the form from the other thread!

Hope that helps